# Raw mp3 files do not appear with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, raw

When I proguard in this way, all R files can be displayed.

```
-keepclassmembers class com.android.android.R$* {public static <fields>;}
-keep class com.android.android.R$*
```

I just want the raw files to be preserved and displayed. Is there something like this for this?

```
-keepclassmembers class com.android.android.R$.raw* {public static <fields>;}
-keep class com.android.android.R$.raw*
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to keep *only* the raw files?

Comment: Yes, I just want to keep raw files out of proguard

Comment: wouldn't `-keep class com.android.android.R$raw { *; }` just work?

Comment: My classes appear as com.android.android.util.MyFragment.d. How can I proguard them all? I thought it was because of this line, but even if I remove it, it doesn't protect all of them completely.

Comment: you can just obfuscate all your classes (I recon) using `-keep public class ** {
   *;
}` or if you want to specify one class do something like `-keep public class com.android.android.util.MyFragment {
   *;
}`

Comment: I need obfuscate all class like this : ```a.b.c.d()``` My proguarded class like this : ```com.android.android.util.MyFragment.d()``` How can I proguard all classes and functions? I know that the ```keep``` function completely remove Proguard for classes.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure you can rename your classes to match that (haven't done that yet), but stuff like `-flattenpackagehierarchy` or `-repackageclasses` or `-allowaccessmodification` could help you with that, however I would just create a new question and ask about it (and maybe link this one)

Comment: OK, can you add the answer to my question below? Maybe someone will benefit from it too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77727204/proguard-all-files-and-classes my new questiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your `Raw` resources all you need is to add:

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.R$raw { *; }
```

assuming your resources are in the `com.example.myapp` package :)