# Proguard all package files and classes

Tags: android, proguard

My proguard file:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,InnerClasses,*Annotation*,Signature,EnclosingMethod

-keep class com.android.android.R$raw { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.material.**
-keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }

-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.* { *; }

-keep class androidx.window.** { *; }

-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
```

I need obfuscate all class like this : `a.b.c.d()`
My proguarded class like this : `com.android.android.util.MyFragment.d()`

How can I proguard all classes and functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find `-classobfuscationdictionary` that might help you achieve that result, but it requires a dictionary file, so if you would create a simple text file (let's name it dictionary.txt) and put a naming scheme there like so:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Then in your ProGuard you may use

```
-classobfuscationdictionary dictionary.txt
```

(also make sure the path to the file is correct in the step above, the path will be different if the file is not in the same directory ProGuard is located)

aaand another side note:

> ProGuard obfuscation does not guarantee that your class names will follow exactly the format. Instead, it ensures that the obfuscated names are valid and unique identifiers. The actual format depends on the size of your dictionary and the complexity of your class hierarchies